# pandas to_csv and from_csv , number of reords mismatch

Tags: pandas

I have this curious problem with pandas (python 3.5)

I am saving a dataframe to csv and then reading the same file back into a dataframe. I get different number of records in the new dataframe. 
The strange thing is that the number of records have increased!!

```
data_n.to_csv('file1.csv')

data_n1=pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

print (len(data_n),len(data_n1),len(data_n1)-len(data_n))

206637 208299 1662
```

---

Here is some code which demonstrates the issue:

```
import pandas as pd

orig = pd.DataFrame({'url':['foo\rbar', 'baz'], 'col':[1, 2]})
orig['idx'] = range(len(orig))
print(orig)
#    col       url  idx
# 0    1  foo\rbar    0
# 1    2       baz    1
orig.to_csv('/tmp/file1.csv')

new = pd.read_csv('/tmp/file1.csv')
print(new)
#   Unnamed: 0  col  url  idx
# 0          0    1  foo  NaN
# 1        bar    0  NaN  NaN
# 2          1    2  baz  1.0
```

Comment: It might help us identify the problem if we see what some of the extra rows look like. If `data_n` has a unique index, you could use `df = data_n1.loc[data_n1.index.difference(data_n.index)]` to isolate the extra rows. Posting `df.reset_index().head().to_dict('list')` would show us what a few of those rows look like in an unambiguous fashion

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used your code and have been to isolate  the problem to a field which stores website urls.  Some of them have a '\r' in the end. It is of type str. For these cases, Pandas is creating an extra row with the index value in place of the website.

Comment: it is also doing something else which is ver strange.  I have added an index:
idx=range(len(data))
data['idx']=idx
print (type(data['idx'].iloc[0])),data['idx'].iloc[0]    . I get the following  : 210885
<class 'numpy.int64'>
Out[47]:
(None, 0)

Comment: it is also doing something else which is very strange.  
I have added an index:

idx=range(len(data))
data['idx']=idx
print (type(data['idx'].iloc[0])),data['idx'].iloc[0]), I get the following output:

<class 'numpy.int64'>
Out[47]:
(None, 0) when 

when I store and retreive the 'idx colum, the type changes to float:

print (type(data_n['idx'].iloc[0])),data_n['idx'].iloc[0])

<class 'numpy.float64'>
Out[49]:
(None, 0.0)
In [50]:

Comment: I've added some code to your question to help people reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The CSV parser called by `pd.read_csv` interprets an unquoted `\r` as end-of-line. 
To protect the `\r` from being interpreted as end-of-lines, pass `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` or `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` to the `to_csv` call. To tell Pandas to interpret the first column as the index, pass `index_col=0` to `pd.read_csv`:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

orig = pd.DataFrame({'url':['foo\rbar', 'baz'], 'col':[1, 2]})
orig['idx'] = range(len(orig))
print(orig)
#    col       url  idx
# 0    1  foo\rbar    0
# 1    2       baz    1
orig.to_csv('/tmp/file1.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

new = pd.read_csv('/tmp/file1.csv', index_col=0)
print(new)
#    col       url  idx
# 0    1  foo\rbar    0
# 1    2       baz    1
```

Alternatively, if you do not need or wish to retain `orig.index`, you could omit
the index from the CSV using

```
orig.to_csv('/tmp/file1.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, index=False)
new = pd.read_csv('/tmp/file1.csv')
```